# Which size spoke tool. Currently size 14

Tags: repair, spokes, wheel-truing

I have this spoke tool. The number I use on this tool is 14. I use it on a hybrid mountain bike.

[image: I have an existing spoke tool].

I want to get one which is easier to use but I do not know which size.

Here are the available sizes.
For 3.20mm/80 ga./0.127" nipples, black vinyl coated.
For 3.45mm/80 ga./0.136" nipples, red vinyl coated.
For 3.30mm/80 ga./0.130” nipples, green vinyl coating

My guess is the red one in the middle. Hoping for someone to confirm my guess.

Thanks you

Edit by Moz: Bounty offered for a **conversion chart or link to one**. Those numbers seem more or less consistent on the three of those tools I found, so somewhere there has to be a reference to the expected sizes (unfortunately theres +/- .1mm wear on the ones I have as they're old and cheap). The suppliers I've found all just say "fits all sizes" and don't list what the sizes actually are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found these sizes from various shop pages which are not worthy for linking here.

So in answer to my own question:

```
8G = ?
10G = 5mm
11G = 4.4mm
12G = 3.96mm
13G = 3.7mm
14G = 3.45mm
15G = 3.3mm
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have the right guess.

If you really cannot get to a bike shop I would suggest that you just order a red 'Spokey' online.

It is unusual in the UK to have to get the yellow 'Spokey' out (for Japanese wheels) and I would be surprised if your hands were so different that a different tool to the legendary 'Spokey' was needed.

If you cannot get to the shop and you are unwilling to gamble on the red 'Spokey' being the right one, just order all three. There are distance selling regulations that mean whomever you order from it is okay to send back the spoke keys that did not fit.

Comment: Which country has "distance selling regulations"?

Comment: The wonders of the European Union - Directive 97/7/EC is colloquially known as 'distance selling laws' in the UK, anywhere else in the E.U. will have the same rule but call it something different. As for 'in the land of the free' it is the law of the jungle, different rules in different states and no common-to-everyone, easy-to-understand laws to facilitate free trade. Tax laws are a particular nightmare for distance selling in the USA. Not sure what the deal is buying direct from China or anywhere else. However, if buying online it is always worth checking laws and small print.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers on your current gauge are almost certainly inverse inches for the nipple size that that gauge spokes used to take. These days there are fewer spoke sizes in common use and only one common thread and nipple size. I can't find a reasonable chart online for the conversion and I have never tried to do it myself. I think [this explanation](http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-188909.html) is probably correct - the cost of buying all three is low and the chance of getting it wrong is high. Just buy one of each and be done with it.

The suggestion in that link of visiting your LBS and asking them to work it out and sell you the appropriate size is probably the best fallback position. It may be more expensive than buying all three online, and the chances of finding a nipple that's the wrong size for your one key is also high. Probably not on your current wheel, but on the next wheel you try it will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I refurbish a lot of old bikes and I use a wrench like you show... There appears to be little uniformity.
However, If you're just dealing with YOUR bike you should be able to pick the right one at the shop...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want the red one for 14ga spokes. 
Just a regular Park Tool (Red) is good enough 99% of the time, but if you are having issues with stuck spokes or rounding off the nipple, the only way to go is with a DT Swiss 4 sided wrench like in this photo. I do a lot of wheels every day, so the higher price of the DT Swiss wrench was worth the investment for myself, but for the average guy working in his garage, it's not. Unless you just need to have the best of everything.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bikes.SE. This is an answer to an already answered 6 year old question? SE is aiming to become a QA site, not discussion, so we want no more than a few answers for future visitors. Adding the same thing to a list benefits no one. (The prefered way, once you get rep's, is edit other posts to improve another answer)